# if then statement in html5

Tags: html, if-statement

I am working in creating a website. I have a page where I have a drop down list and I want to make it so that when the user selects the option "Other" a text box comes up. How do I do that?

Here's my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <html lang = "en">
 <body>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <h1>What would you like it to say?</h1>

 <p>Commmon Requests:</p>

 <form action="input" action="random.html" method="get">
 <select name="requests">
 <option value="blank"> </option>
 <option value="good morning sir">Good Morning Sir</option>
 <option value="good morning madam">Good Morning Madam</option>
 <option value="other">Other</option>   
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </select>
 </form>

 <br><br><textarea rows="3" cols="30">
 Write a request here if you would like to hear it.
 </textarea>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You should keep the submit button outside the drop down list.

Comment: if my answer is exact what you need then accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang = "en">
 <body>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <h1>What would you like it to say?</h1>

        <p>Common Requests:</p>

        <form action="input" action="random.html" method="get">

        <select name="requests" onchange="checkIfOther();" id="dropDown1">

        <option value="blank"> </option>
        <option value="good morning sir">Good Morning Sir</option>
        <option value="good morning madam">Good Morning Madam</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>

        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

        <div id="other" style="display:none">

            <label>Other(Please explain):</label><input type="text" id="otherText"/>


        </div>

        <br><br><textarea rows="3" cols="30">
        Write a request here if you would like to hear it.
        </textarea>

 </body>
 </html>

<script>

    function checkIfOther(){

        a = document.getElementById("dropDown1");        

        if(a.value == "other")           

            document.getElementById("other").setAttribute("style","display:inline");

        else

            document.getElementById("other").setAttribute("style","display:none");


        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Attach an "onchange" event to your select element with a function which checks which option is the selected value and if it is the "Other" option, change a hidden text box from being hidden to being visible. Example below:

```
<form action="input" action="random.html" method="get">
    <select id="requestDropDown" name="requests" onchange="checkOption()">
        ....
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="otherBox" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
</form>
```

I added the input element which is hidden and will be shown if you select the "other" option.

Then, in the `checkOption()` function do your checking to see if Other is selected and change visibility based on that. For example:

```
function checkOption(){
    //This will fire on changing of the value of "requests"
    var dropDown = document.getElementById("requestDropDown");
    var textBox = document.getElementById("otherBox");

    if(dropDown.value == "other"){
        textBox.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

}
```

It's simple and concise.

Answer (score 2):

> [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mCkvW/)
>
> html

```
<body>
<p id="demo">
</p>
<h1>
    What would you like it to say?</h1>
<p>
    Commmon Requests:</p>
<form action="input" id="form1" action="random.html" method="get">
<select name="requests" onchange="check(this)">
    <option value="blank"></option>
    <option value="good morning sir">Good Morning Sir</option>
    <option value="good morning madam">Good Morning Madam</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<textarea rows="3" cols="30">
```

Write a request here if you would like to hear it.

> Javascript

```
function check(that) {
        if (that.value === "other") {
            var textBox = document.createElement('input');
            textBox.setAttribute("type", "text");
            textBox.setAttribute("id", "newTextBox");
            document.getElementById('form1').appendChild(textBox);
        }

        else {
            var box = document.getElementById('newTextBox');
            if (box)
                box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple to achieve using Javascript. Do not use HTML for anything other than structuring your website content.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="requests" onchange="openbox(this);">
    ...
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
</form>
...
<textarea rows="3" cols="30" hidden>
Write a request here if you would like to hear it.
</textarea>
```

And in Javaascript,

```
function openbox(requests) {
    if(requests.selectedIndex == 3) {
       //Remove the 'hidden' property'
    } else {
       //Add the 'hidden' property
    }
}
```

EDIT: When you said text box, I thought of an alert for some reason. 
W3C School Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp